# Asynchronous write stream and response stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, express

I have some basic code which streams a file from the cache, or downloads it to the cache if it isn't present:

```
if (fs.existsSync('cache/' + req.params.image)) {
  fs.createReadStream('cache/' + req.params.image).pipe(res);
}else{
  request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('cache/' + req.params.image));
}
```

The issue is that in order to display a new file, the page must be loaded twice. Once to write to the cache and once to read from the cache. What I want to do is pipe `request` to both `createWriteStream` and `res` at the same time, asynchronously (so not just wait for the pipe close event to write to the response).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (fs.existsSync('./' + req.params.image)) {
    fs.createReadStream('./' + req.params.image).pipe(res);
}else{
    var fetch = request(url);
    fetch.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./' + req.params.image));
    req.pipe(fetch).pipe(res);  
}
```

Hope this does the trick...